# under mac php shows Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class, but under linux everything runs fine

Tags: php

The error message is

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Zbcommon in /Users/apple/Sites/maemvl.com/application/libraries/Zbcommon.php on line 3
```

But there is no other duplicated class exist.
And the message only shows under mac. Under linux server everything works fine.
The code is same between both mac and linux, I coudn't figure out where is the problem.

Comment: could you show some related.. code

Comment: I had the same on Win - there were no redeclaring, but in Linux - the were redaclaring. Check under Mac OS the file with same name but with different case.

Comment: Can only guess it's a filename/class name caseing issue.  Windows fileystem is always case-insensitive and Mac OS is case-insensitive by default, but linux is case-sensitive.

Comment: @Sudhir it's a really big class...too long for here.

Answer (score 0):

The above suggested posts make sense. Mostly the case sensitive issues.

First: Set error_reporting to E_ALL if not done yet.

Then: Check the include_path() and any autoloaders. Since that might resolve your issue. The inlude path is of great influence when including files. Mostly when not using absolute paths this might give you issues like you experience.

Comment: I followed the steps. But still doesn't work. When I change the name of this class. It shows missing required class from other files. And in the relative file, the codes are 'require_once(APPROOT.'/'.APPPATH."/libraries/zbcommon.php");
  $this->zbcommon = new Zbcommon();', is the 'new Zbcommon()' make the class duplicated?

Comment: Please add the values of your APPROOT and APPPATH, are they equal to the path in the start post? If that is true then this file has already been included but somehow this doesn't stop require_once from including it. Thinking about that: Just leave the require_once because the class is already available? Check your full source code for "autoload". That might be why the file is already available.